# Can external cause ever be discounted?

Tags: causality

We are often advised not to confuse [correlation with causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Fortunately techniques do exist to assess the likelihood that an outcome does indeed result from a cause. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_cross_mapping) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_controlled_trial)

But in some cases it is not possible/realistic to perform a randomized controlled trial.  (For example, when assessing the causal relationship between [religious belief and happiness](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2016/02/02/office-for-national-statistics-well-being-data_n_9138076.html), practical and ethical constraints may prevent us from inducing religious (dis)belief or (un)happiness on a statistically significant scale.)

If a randomized controlled trial is not possible, is there any way to counter the argument that there is a third as yet **unestablished** cause to both the observed phenomenon?

Comment: My immediate thought is that scientific practice addresses this problem in general, by hypothesising counter-examples and then testing them to see if they confirm or contradict the theory. This provides compelling support for the theory, even if it is not quantifiable. Hopefully someone with more expert knowledge can describe this and other such practices more accurately.

Comment: This article by Michael Nielsen appears to address some similar concerns: [If correlation doesn’t imply causation, then what does?](http://www.michaelnielsen.org/ddi/if-correlation-doesnt-imply-causation-then-what-does/)